# LAN clients get no IPv6 after OpenWrt upgrade to 21.02.0-rc1

Tags: networking, router, lan, ipv6, openwrt

As the title says my home router's LAN clients, both on cable, and on wireless, don't get any IPv6 address from the router.

---

Formerly, it functioned without problems.

Here's my current IPv6 server settings page (don't worry, can be enlarged):

[image: OpenWrt IPv6 server settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [discussion thread](https://forum.openwrt.org/t/solved-lan-clients-no-ipv6-ra-mtu-option-in-etc-config-dhcp-causes-problems/94550), it seems to be a bug.

Don't worry, the solution is very simple, just change the value of **RA MTU** to 1500 or something suitable for your network.

I rebooted, (but there may be another way of making this setting effective immediately), and my clients have their IPv6 back.